# Vue module component detect Vue.js version?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3

I have a component I'd like to release to NPM with simple `v-model` functionality.

as such, it'd be ideal if it could run on vuejs 2/3 interchangeably.

I can brute force the behaviour for both by setting the component to emit `input` and `update:modelValue` but a more elegant solution would be to verify the user's implementation and emit accordingly. Is there a "version" property available somewhere in the toolchain at runtime?  Alternatively, what would be the (or one of the) best way(s) to gracefully detect the version of the client's build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Vue 3:**

```js
import * as Vue from 'vue';

console.log(Vue.version) // "3.0.0"
```

**Vue 2:**

```js
import Vue from 'vue';

console.log(Vue.version) // "2.6.12"
```

---

To make a valid determination between the two, you can do this:

```js
import * as Vue from 'vue';

// Make copy to prevent import warning in Vue 2
const vueObject = { ...Vue };
let version;

if (vueObject.default) version = 2;
if (vueObject.version && vueObject.version[0] === '3') {
    version = 3;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With: `Vue.version`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'

console.log(Vue.version);

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Reference: https://www.positronx.io/how-to-check-current-vue-js-application-version/